# Self-Updating, Download, Extract, and Replace Exe

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, C#, WPF.

I'm trying to give `MyProgram.exe` the ability to easily update itself.

I have code that downloads the file `MyProgram.7z` to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Temp\`.

From the `7z` it extracts `MyProgram.exe` to the currently running `MyProgram.exe`'s directory.

While the 7-Zip extraction is starting, the program closes itself to allow overwriting the exe.

```
// AppData Temp Directory
string tempDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

// MyProgram.exe Current Directory
string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().TrimEnd('\\') + @"\";


// ...
//
// Download Code Here
// Saves MyProgram.7z to AppData Temp
//
// ...


// Unzip MyProgram.7z
// Overwrite MyProgram.exe
//
using (Process extract = new Process())
{
    extract.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    extract.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    extract.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    extract.StartInfo.FileName = "7z.exe";
    extract.StartInfo.Arguments = "-r -y e " + "\"" + tempDir + "MyProgram.7z" + "\"" + " -o\"" + currentDir + "\"" + " *";
    // 7z.exe -r -y e "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\MyProgram.7z" -o"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\" *

    extract.Start();
}


// Exit Program
// 7-Zip will continue to run in the background after MyProgram.exe has exited
//
Environment.Exit(0);
```

I've tested it and it appears to work.

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there anything that can go wrong with this way? I'like to have it within the program and not in a separate helper program. I also need to use `7z.exe` in this case.

Is there a way to instead launch `cmd` and chain commands into it like `timeout 5 && 7z.exe ...` and have it relaunch the program after extraction?

Comment: You might want to checkout _ClickOnce_

Comment: you could do the reverse: Copy your program and all it's dlls to a tmp folder, start it from there then exit the current running instance then check for updates and extract the update directly into the 'real' program folder. Works more reliably I would imagine and you have more control over the entire process and can reverse it if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows). It is an open-source library that completely manages both installation and updates of desktop Windows applications.

There is a getting starting guide available on GitHub: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/getting-started/0-overview.md.

There is also the ClickOnce deployment technology from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx.

No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching `7z` process directly you can also:

1. launch `cmd /c` process that will wait 5 seconds, then unzip, the relaunch the app
2. shutdown yourself

`cmd /c timeout 5 & [your unzip command] & MyProgram.exe`

PS. `&` is used to execute multiple commands one after another